# Flutter CustomPainter paints on animations

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-custompainter, materialapp

I have an extended `CustomPainter` class inside a `MaterialApp` widget tree. Unfortunately, the `paint` method gets invoked multiple times during the intrinsic Material design animations (for instance when hovering over a BottomNavigationBarItem or when the Drawer opens).

This happens even though the `shouldRepaint` method returns always `false`.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: you cannot avoid this, of course you can wrap it with `RepaintBoundary` widget but this does not pay off really - btw what's wrong with the current behaviour?

Comment: I just want the app to be more energy efficient and avoid unnecessary canvas repaints.

Comment: so use `RepaintBoundary` as a parent to `CustomPaint`

Comment: but as I said you should not worry about those "extra" repaints, it does not really pays off